# p/P always puts the cursor after the put, as though the command was gp/gP

Tags: paste

When I put using `p` or `P`, the cursor ends up at the end of the put. As far as I can remember it has always done this. I just realised that this is not the usual behaviour and that you need to use `gp` or `gP` for this normally. I get exactly the same behaviour with `p` and `gp`, `P` and `gP`.

But this also happens when I start vim using the `--clean` switch, so I confused about why this is happening.

I am currently using Windows 11 with wsl and the Linux versions of vim and nvim and the Windows versions of vim and gvim, where it happens on all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. `p/P` puts the cursor on the last character of the put text. `gp/gP` puts the cursor on the column *after* the put text, if it exists; if the last character of the put text is the last character of that line, then `gp/gP` cannot put the cursor on the next column, and so behaves like `p/P`.

Here is an example. Say we have this text (the caret sign shows where the cursor is):

```
text1
text2
^
```

After copying "text1" into the register, if we press `p`, the content of the buffer will be this:

```
text1
text2
ttext1ext2
     ^
```

But if we pressed `gp`, the buffer would have contained this:

```
text1
ttext1ext2
      ^
```

You were probably testing this on a line where there was no character after the put text, which is why `gp/gP` was behaving the same as `p/P`.